# Creation of new row dependent on date in another column

Tags: r

Im struggling with a wrangling task at the moment and any help would be appreciated.

See DF

| Var 1 | Date |
| --- | --- |
| P1 | 13/09/2020 |
| P2 | 13/09/2020 |
| P3 | 20/09/2020 |
| P4 | 20/09/2020 |
| P5 | 27/09/2020 |
| P6 | 27/09/2020 |

Date is in %d/%m/%Y format and is currently ordered descending with the earliest date first. My intent is to have the earliest date as Gameweek 1 and when the date changes, the row input is Gameweek 2. See my intended DF:

| Var 1 | Date | Gameweek |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 13/09/2020 | Gameweek 1 |
| P2 | 13/09/2020 | Gameweek 1 |
| P3 | 20/09/2020 | Gameweek 2 |
| P4 | 20/09/2020 | Gameweek 2 |
| P5 | 27/09/2020 | Gameweek 3 |
| P6 | 27/09/2020 | Gameweek 3 |

Again, any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `factor`.

```
df$Gameweek <-factor(df$Date, labels='Gameweek')
```

```
Sample Output

  Var1       Date  Gameweek
1   P1 13/09/2020 Gameweek1
2   P2 13/09/2020 Gameweek1
3   P3 20/09/2020 Gameweek2
4   P4 20/09/2020 Gameweek2
5   P5 27/09/2020 Gameweek3
6   P6 27/09/2020 Gameweek3
```

Comment: This solution assigns a random number to the Game week rather than being from 1 onwards. I.e. my earliest date is being labelled as Gameweek19. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post some sample data that demonstrates that?

Comment: Not in your example data. Are your real data sorted by `Date`?  Is `Date` a character or date field? Use `dput(head(DF, 10))` to provide your data, not a table which leaves out critical information.

Comment: My mistake, the date field was as character so adjusted this to as.date and now this works. Will look to use dput in later questions. Thanks for your help both.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
group_by(Date) %>%
mutate(Gameweek = paste("Gameweek", rownumber(), sep=" "))
```